# React router v6.0.0-beta.1 go back / pop history

Tags: react-router

I am trying to implement "go back" functionality for a page that could be access from `n` different urls.

Example, all the following URLs will link to `abc.com/b1`:

```
abc.com/a1
abc.com/a2
abc.com/a3
abc.com/a4
...
abc.com/an
```

From `abc.com/b1` I want to support a link that takes you back to the previous page you visited.

My first attempt is to use:

```
...

const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate(-1);

...
```

However, if you land straight in `abc.com/b1` `navigate(-1)` will likely take you outside of my application into some other site, or browser `about:blank`.

What is the best approach to implement such functionality?

- is there a way to access the history length to check wether we should `navigate(-1)` or push a new page?
- should I pass additional state/query from `a` pages to `b`? so `b` knows how to go back? this seems like overkill.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was with the same problem, but I finally found a solution that worked for me.

I'm using the `react-router-dom@6.2.1`.

```
// Simply return to the previous page or to the initial route
navigate('..')
```

Comment: wouldn't navigate('..') go back 1 level? and not necessarily to the previous url?

Example starting: "foo.com/start" navigated to "foo.com/segment1/segment2". Then using navigate('..') would go to: "foo.com/segment1" instead of "foo.com/start"